# How can I check how many edits a user has made?

Tags: discussion

I would like to know how many posts I have edited.

How can I check this? Can I also check how many edits another user has made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see this number, along with a complete listing, at https://stackoverflow.com/users/1953016/ankit-agrawal?tab=activity&sort=revisions

(Or, more generally, from the Revisions tab under Activity from any user's profile)